# NSDate / NSCalender count days in year

Tags: xcode, nsdate, nscalendar

I am making an app that calculates salaries based on the years somebody is working for a firm. The user enter 2 dates, the first one is the day he started working (let's say 1/12/2010) and the second is the end date (let's say 1/02/2012). So far i know the total days he worked but **i want to be more specific** in order to calculate that he worked:

```
30 days in 2010 * 30$ per day = 90$
365 days in 2011 * 35$ per day = 12775$
32 days in 2012 * 40$ per day = 1280$
```

It's the first time i am working with dates and calendars and as you can guess i am totally unfamiliar with them.

Comment: If you know the start and end date... that what else you want to know? use date and calender components and find the differnce, dates etc.

Comment: The start / end date are given by the user and might have up to 30 years difference. Please read carefully what i want to do.

Comment: so 3 yrs or 30 years what the problem in that?

Comment: I need to know how many days in each year he worked. See my example. I don't think i can make it any simpler. Do you know how to translate my example into actual code?

Comment: from nscalender u can find number of dates, loop through all the years and months.

Comment: its 1AM in India. I will try to solve this problem...tomorw if it remains un-answered :)

Comment: Propably, what you suggest is what i am looking for but i don't know how to implement it...

Comment: my last comment for today... even in stack overflow..u will find thousands of questions on date, calender. to find differnce between two dates and all. try reading few of them, u will be able to solve. otherwise someone will help u. And i will check if no-answer will be here i will post my answer.

Comment: I can not understand why people downvoted my question?! Was the answer so obvious to anybody than me?

Comment: I upvoted... But actually this question was nothing more than doing some logical coding. Even someone can post better/shorter/faster solution than me. And this question is specific to you only, and the solution contains so many parts of other questions... so making it a copy-paste stuff from many other questions. So few people downvoted.

Comment: And what i feel is, you get more downvotes than upvotes... :D

Comment: Actually this was my only downvoted question. :(

Comment: in my above comment...  i referred **you** to everyone, including me. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
-(NSInteger)daysBetweenTwoDates:(NSDate *)fromDateTime andDate:(NSDate*)toDateTime{

    NSDate *fromDate;
    NSDate *toDate;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&fromDate interval:NULL forDate:fromDateTime];
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&toDate interval:NULL forDate:toDateTime];

    NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

    return [difference day]+1;//+1 as if start and end both date are same, so 1 day worked.
}

- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    NSDate *startDate=[self.startDate dateValue];//taking from datepicker
    NSDate *endDate=[self.endDate dateValue];//taking from datepicker

    NSTimeZone *gmt=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterYYYY=[NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatterYYYY setTimeZone:gmt];
    [dateFormatterYYYY setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterDDMMYYYY=[NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatterDDMMYYYY setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/YYYY"];
    [dateFormatterDDMMYYYY setTimeZone:gmt];


    //1. startDate to 31/12/StartDateYear
    //2. loop to endDateYear
    //3. 01/01/endDateYear to endDate

    /* step 1 */
    //find 31/12/StartDateYear
    NSLog(@"YYYY ; %@",[dateFormatterYYYY stringFromDate:startDate]);

    NSString *lastDateOfStartYearString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"31/12/%@",[dateFormatterYYYY stringFromDate:startDate]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatddMMyyyy=[NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatddMMyyyy setDateFormat:@"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"];
    NSDate *lastDateOfStartYear=[dateFormatddMMyyyy dateFromString:lastDateOfStartYearString];

    //no. of days
    NSInteger year=[[dateFormatterYYYY stringFromDate:startDate]integerValue];
    NSInteger days=[self daysBetweenTwoDates:startDate andDate:lastDateOfStartYear];

    //add in dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *daysForYearDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    [daysForYearDictionary setValue:@(days) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",year]];



    /* step 2*/
    NSInteger nextYearAfterStart=[[dateFormatterYYYY stringFromDate:startDate]integerValue]+1;
    NSInteger previousYearBeforeEnd=[[dateFormatterYYYY stringFromDate:endDate]integerValue]-1;

    for (NSInteger yearCounter=nextYearAfterStart; yearCounter<=previousYearBeforeEnd; yearCounter++) {

        NSString *firstDateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1/1/%ld",yearCounter];
        NSDate *firstDate=[dateFormatddMMyyyy dateFromString:firstDateString];

        NSString *lastDateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"31/12/%ld",yearCounter];
        NSDate *lastDate=[dateFormatddMMyyyy dateFromString:lastDateString];

        //no. of days
        days=[self daysBetweenTwoDates:firstDate andDate:lastDate];
        //add in dictionary
        [daysForYearDictionary setValue:@(days) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",yearCounter]];
    }



    /* step 3 */
    //find 1/1/EndDateYear
    NSString *firstDateOfStartYearString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1/1/%@",[dateFormatterYYYY stringFromDate:endDate]];
    NSDate *firstDateOfEndYear=[dateFormatddMMyyyy dateFromString:firstDateOfStartYearString];

    //no. of days
    year=[[dateFormatterYYYY stringFromDate:endDate]integerValue];
    days=[self daysBetweenTwoDates:firstDateOfEndYear andDate:endDate];
    //add in dictionary
    [daysForYearDictionary setValue:@(days) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",year]];




    //printing
    for (NSString *yearStr in daysForYearDictionary) {
        NSLog(@"Year : %@, Days Worked : %@",yearStr,[daysForYearDictionary valueForKey:yearStr]);
    }

}
```